# How to optimize my mongodb query using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, query-optimization, pymongo

I use these code to query my data inside the mongodb, but I don't know why it took so long to get the result (around 5mins)

```
import pymongo
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

load_dotenv()

SRV = os.getenv("SRV")

client = pymongo.MongoClient(SRV)
db = client["production"]
coll = db["woocommerce_order"]
# coll.create_index("store_id")

test = list(coll.find(
    {
        "store_id": ObjectId("60831690eca6bcddcecfc69c")
    },
    {
        "_id": 0,
        "store_id": 1,
        "total_value": 1,
        "total_items": 1,
        "line_items": 1,
        "total_tax": 1,
        "billing": 1,
        "date_created": 1,
    }
))

# print(test["executionStats"])
print(test)
```

I've try to create index but it doesn't really help. My collection has around 200k documents.
Anybody has any idea to optimize the query?

Comment: You can verify the usage of index in a query, with the `explain` option on the query.

Comment: If the query took 5 minutes, the mongod log should have an line that gives a little bit of detail about it.

Comment: thanks for the help, but where can i find that mongodb log?